# Selenium: Read/Write into Excel file during parallel execution

Tags: java, selenium, apache-poi

When I tried to access excel file for read/write operation during parallel execution, I am getting "**org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)**" exception. Is there any way to handle excel file during parallel execution as more than one driver is trying to modify the contents of the excel file.
I have two session of chrome driver executing parallely (Chrome driver version updated to latest: 79.0.3945.36, Chrome browser version: 79.0.3945.130)

Please have a look into TestNG stack trace for first driver

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:9096
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
System info: host: 'LT-HARSHA', ip: '10.212.134.203', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '13.0.2'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:92)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:181)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:168)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:157)
at com.hec.TestScripts.ContactsOutreach.checkModuleFlagContactsOutreach(ContactsOutreach.java:95)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:62)
at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:340)
at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurations(ConfigInvoker.java:294)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:176)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:122)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:9096
at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:247)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:165)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:257)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:135)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:114)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:77)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.OkHttpClient.execute(OkHttpClient.java:103)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:105)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:74)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
... 20 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:579)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:549)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:597)
at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:339)
at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:603)
at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:129)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:245)
... 42 more
```

Please have a look into TestNG stack trace for second driver

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
System info: host: 'LT-HARSHA', ip: '10.212.134.203', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '13.0.2'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:202)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:188)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:79)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:181)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:168)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:157)
at com.hec.TestScripts.PatientSearch.checkModuleFlagPatientSearch(PatientSearch.java:96)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:62)
at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:340)
at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurations(ConfigInvoker.java:294)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:176)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:122)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for [http://localhost:5588/status] to be available after 20001 ms
at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:100)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:197)
... 22 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:204)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:156)
at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:75)
... 23 more
```

Comment: Is it possible to consolidate all the results and update the excel at once, rather doing it for each test?

Comment: I have to update the result of execution for each test case in corresponding driver session. Even though I consolidate the results, at the end all the drivers in parallel will access and write result into excel

Comment: Nobody will be able to help knowing only that small part of an exception stack trace. But how the question is asked apart from that, the answer is no. See [Can I access/modify workbooks/documents/slideshows in multiple threads?](https://poi.apache.org/help/faq.html#faq-N10224)

Comment: Hi, I have added TestNG stack trace for 2 drivers which is executing parallel.

Comment: Also note that "org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)" is appearing in the console only